# Is there a way of shortening fat-arrow functions?

Tags: code-golf, tips, javascript, recursion

From what I've seen throughout my time here on PPCG, most JavaScript entries involving fat arrow functions tend to be one of two camps:

1. The simple ones that are capable of running as a single statement and returning an answer, straight off the bat, like `x=(a,b)=>a*a+b`
2. The more complex ones that usually have curly braces because of the use of loops, and as a result require the use of a `return` statement.. like `p=b=>{m=b;for(a=1;~-m;)--m,a*=m*m;return a%b}`

Taking the above example from category 2 with the curly braces concept as proof-of-concept... Would there be a way to re-golf this code (or similar) like this so as to eliminate the curly braces as well as the `return`? I'm only asking this as this could *potentially* (not saying this will happen all the time) eliminate 8 bytes from a JS golfer's code. Are there any techniques that one could use in this instance? I've tried recursion, but the `m=b` statement has proven to be a bit of a bugbear, as I can't seem to shake it.

For the above code, how would one golf that further so as to eliminate the `return` statement, regardless of whether it golfs shorter or not?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Use Recursion

I've found that recursion is (almost) always shorter than `eval`+`for`. The general way to convert from for to eval is:

```
for(a=n;b;c);d
(f=a=>b?f(c):d)(n)
```

So let's see your example:

```
b=>{m=b;for(a=1;~-m;)--m,a*=m*m;return a%b}
```

We can first simplify it to:

```
for(m=b,a=1;~-m;--m,a*=m*m)a%b;
```

What did we do here? Well we simply moved everything inside the `for` statement, this helps us reduce the amount of semicolons which is not directly better but almost always leads to some golf.

---

Let's put this in eval and compare it to the recursion version:

```
b=>{m=b;for(a=1;~-m;)--m,a*=m*m;return a%b}
b=>eval('for(m=b,a=1;~-m;--m,a*=m*m)a%b')
b=>(f=a=>~-m?(--m,f(a*=m*m)):a%b)(1,m=b)
```

The first part of the for loop (`a=n`), we can start that off by passing those variables in as arguments. The condition is simply: `b?(c,f(a)):d` where `d` is the return value. Usually `c` just modifies `a` so it can be merged into it. So we can golf it even more using what I've mentioned:

```
b=>(f=a=>~-m?(--m,f(a*=m*m)):a%b)(1,m=b)
b=>(f=a=>~-m?f(a*=--m*m):a%b)(1,m=b) // --m moved into a*=
b=>(f=a=>--m?f(a*=m*m):a%b)(1,m=b) // --m moved to condition
```

That said, as noted by @Niel is simplifying your algorithm. An algorithm golfy in one language may not be golfy in another so make sure to try different algoriths and compare them.

Comment: You've missed a big saving in simplifying the original code. `~-m` is `m-1`, so the loop can be `for(m=b,a=1;--m;a*=m*m)a%b;` and the recursive version can be (untested) `b=>(f=a=>--m?f(a*=m*m):a%b)(1,m=b)`

Comment: Sometimes you just have to use a different algorithm but in this case the best I could do was the same length as @PeterTaylor's answer: `b=>b>1&(f=a=>--a<2||b%a&&f(a))(b)`

Answer (score 11):

## Abuse eval.

It's simple. Instead of:

```
f=n=>{for(i=c=0;i<n;i++)c+=n;return c}
```

Use

```
f=n=>eval("for(i=c=0;i<n;i++)c+=n;c")
```

Eval returns the last evaluated statement. In this case, since the last evaluated statement would be `c+=n`, we would be left with `c` anyhow, saving two bytes.

```
f=n=>eval("for(i=c=0;i<n;i++)c+=n")
```

In general:

```
f=n=>eval("code;x")
```

is shorter than this, by a byte:

```
f=n=>{code;return x}
```

---

As a note, using graves to call eval to possibly save bytes doesn't work, since:

```
eval`string`
```

is equivalent to

```
["string"]
```

Helpful for obfuscation! Not so much for code golf.

Comment: `foo\`string\`` is always equivalent to `foo(["string"])`, it's just that many functions then cast the array back to the desired string.

Comment: @Neil Oh, how interesting!